# unable to fetch data from firestore in flutter with null safety enabled

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, dart-null-safety

I'm trying to make a simple flutter application connected with cloud_firestore. I'm using the null safety enabled versions. I did according to the documentation example. But i got the error while compiling and executing the code.

Below is my code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("movies").doc().snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context,
          AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text("Something Went Wrong");
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Text("Loading");
        }

        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return new ListView(
            children: snapshot.data.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
              Map<String, dynamic> data =
                  document.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
              return new ListTile(
                title: new Text(data['name']),
              );
            }).toList(),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

This is the error I got:

```
Error: The getter 'docs' isn't defined for the class 'DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>?'.
 - 'DocumentSnapshot' is from 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-2.2.2/lib/cloud_firestore.dart').
 - 'Map' is from 'dart:core'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'docs'.

children: snapshot.data.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                                    ^^^^
lib/main.dart:25:16: Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'Widget' doesn't allow null.

 - 'Widget' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
      builder: (BuildContext context,
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is here:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("movies").doc().snapshots()
```

You are refering to a `doc()` and not a collection. The example from the documentation is for a collection. Try to remove the `doc()` from your code and it should work.

The reason for the error is that a `collection` is a map of multiple `docs` but if you refer just to a single `doc()` like in your code you will get only a single `doc` and then the snapshot you recive doesn't have the getter `docs` as explained in the error message.